# Connecting to a ZNC bouncer with hexchat using an ssl certificate?

Tags: irc

I'd like to get hexchat to connect automatically to my ZNC bouncer. I have certificate authentication configured, which means that when I connect with a valid certificate I don't need to send a password: I just need to send a username and network name.

E.g., to connect to Freenode, I might send:

```
PASS larsks/freenode:
```

Using hexchat I can configure a client certificate, but I can't figure out how to get it to *also* send the `PASS` command; after configuring certificate authentication the `Password:` textbox is disabled in the Freenode settings dialog.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Which option are you selecting for "Login method"?

Comment: I am using "SASL EXTERNAL (cert)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to select "SASL EXTERNAL" in order to send a certificate. HexChat always sends the client certificate as long as it finds one, so you can choose whatever auth method you need. (Besides that, ZNC does not support accepting SASL authentication in the first place.)

The 'EXTERNAL' mechanism itself does not exchange any data at all – it just provides a synchronization point to ensure that the certificate has been processed. (Otherwise on most IRC networks it's done asynchronously.)

Second, the only thing you have in the password field is the *username*, not the actual password. While bouncers traditionally accept it as part of the password, there *is* [a separate field for the username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr0c2.png) which is accepted by ZNC.

[image]

Comment: I spotted the username field, but it didn't appear to get sent. Let me fix up the login method and see if that works better.

Comment: I had to set the login method to "Server password" and then set the Password field to `larsks/freenode:`. Setting the username field or leaving it blank didn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: This page helped me: https://wiki.znc.in/HexChat